# Align TextViews in specific way

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, layout, textview

I am currently learning some techniques in Android and I would like to add TextViews via button press (via Java) into the app (View). But before they get added through code I want to attach to each `TextView` a self made preconfigurartion style from **"res/values/styles.xml"**. That is the main idea so far.

Basically I would like to know how to configure my TextViews (in styles.xml) and the given Layout (e.g. main_activity.xml) in the XML file of an Activity in such a way so they look like in this picture:

[image: Like so]

So the goal is to preconfigure the Layout and TextView in such a way, that I only have to add the TextViews one after another so that they align themselfes in the way like in the picture.

What do I have to do exactly in order to achieve this?

**// main_activity.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView style="@style/AddedTextView" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    
    ...

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_add"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**// res/values/styles.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AddedTextView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.TextView">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_textview_design</item>
        <item name="android:text">TestTV</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/common_text_color</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">7pt</item>
        <item name="android:layout_alignParentLeft">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the style programmatically using a `ContextThemeWrapper`:

```
val textView = TextView(ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AddedTextView))
```

And to add `TextView`s connected to one another and wrap them vertically, you can use the Google's [`FlexBoxLayout`](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)

Here's the basic layout:

```
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/flexLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:flexDirection="row"
    app:flexWrap="wrap">

</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```

And adding the views programmatically is very straightforward:

```
val flexboxLayout = findViewById<View>(R.id.flexLayout) as FlexboxLayout

for (i in 1..50) {
    val textView = TextView(ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AddedTextView))
    val layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT)
    layoutParams.rightMargin = 40
    textView.layoutParams = layoutParams
    textView.text = "TextView $i"
    flexboxLayout.addView(textView)
}
```

[image]